# What is the best way to implement dynamic search on the server from iOS application?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, search, grand-central-dispatch

I'm struggling with a problem of implementing dynamic search.

Here what i want to achieve:

In my application there is an option that user (program manager) will be able to search his team members. Each PM has its account on the server side (web service) where it is a table team_members which contains all the team members that correspond to this manager.
Their amount can be more than hundreds.

And client side app which I develop has an option search team members.
 I want to implement it dynamically:
 e.g When the user print first letter `a` I make a query to the server and get all the matches with a letter:   Antuan, BArrow, etc.

Then user print `ab` and I make a query which must return Abraham, Abdulla, etc. And so on. All the matching results is shown in `UITableView`.
 HTTP query to server is made each time text in `UITextField` shanges. I implement it with `dispatch_async`: on `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` I create a `dispatch_async` where i make an HTTP request with `searchbar.text`.

The problem: it works very slow. I often get an exception `bad selector was sent to the instance`.

So my question:
Why is my approach bad? What is a better solution for this?
Or dynamic search it is a VERY bad idea and I must do search only on clicking some button?

Thanks. I hope some experienced iOS developers  will give me good advice.

Answer (score 2):

Making an HTTP request every time someone types a character is probably never going to be fast enough (nor does it really make sense -- read on). For a certain size of list, the answer would be to pull over the whole list in the background as soon as you present the field (but before the user starts typing in it). Once you have the list, you can start matching, in memory, on the local device.  "More than hundreds" isn't very specific, and it depends on network speed, but I'd guess that if your list is less than 50K in payload size, pulling the whole thing will be the easiest way.

If the list is too big for that to be practical, but the list limited by the first character the user types is not too big, then the best approach might be to wait for the first character, fire off your HTTP request asynchronously, and only start the dynamic match once you've received the response containing all items that start with that letter. One thing to keep in mind is this: if you have the list limited by the first character, that's the only HTTP request you ever have to make (unless the user changes the first character) because all possibilities starting with that letter will be in that list. From there, you can pare down the list locally without any further HTTP requests.

As for why you're getting exceptions, it's hard to say without seeing your actual code. Try setting an exception breakpoint in Xcode. This will allow you to stop in the debugger when the exception is thrown, which will show you what's causing it.